# Problems deploying updated code to Linux 2 AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: asp.net-core, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

When I deploy a ASP .NET Core site from Visual Studio, it shows a new version label and it looks like it deploys successfully, however the code is never updated. Below are the events. The health is "Unknown" and if I go to request the last 100 lines of the log, I click to download and see a blank page. Not sure what else to try here.

> 2021-06-27 20:36:18 UTC-0400  INFO
> Deleted log fragments for this environment.
> 2021-06-27 20:36:14 UTC-0400  INFO
> Environment health has transitioned from Info to Unknown. Application update completed 17 > seconds ago and took 88 seconds. None of the instances are sending data.
> 2021-06-27 20:35:09 UTC-0400  INFO
> Environment update completed successfully.
> 2021-06-27 20:35:09 UTC-0400  INFO
> Successfully deployed new configuration to environment.
> 2021-06-27 20:35:09 UTC-0400  INFO
> New application version was deployed to running EC2 instances.
> 2021-06-27 20:34:16 UTC-0400  INFO
> Deploying new version to instance(s).
> 2021-06-27 20:34:14 UTC-0400  INFO
> Environment health has transitioned from Unknown to Info. Application update in progress > (running for 26 seconds). None of the instances are sending data.
> 2021-06-27 20:33:42 UTC-0400  INFO
> Updating environment projectweb-env-1's configuration settings.
> 2021-06-27 20:33:35 UTC-0400  INFO
> Environment update is starting.

UPDATE: after deploying a new version from visual studio, it never updates unless I go to EC2 and terminate the instance and the site will be updated after a new instance is created. Is this the only way to update an elastic beanstalk site?

Comment: In order to get an answer on this one, you should describe your case in more details so we can try to reproduce the error. BR

Comment: Hi, I am running an ASP .NET Core site on Linux 2 elastic beanstalk. I was able to deploy an initial site but haven't been able to update it since. When I try to get the last 100 lines of the log, it is always an empty text file. The health is "Unknown" and says "None of the instances are sending data." however the initial site I deployed is still available on the site and I can access it without problem. Without being able to see any logs I am  not sure how to solve this. We use Azure but figured we would try AWS a shot but not a great first experience.

Comment: As I remember Elastic Beanstalk, there are lot of options regarding e.g. deployment. You should add enough information in your question so that anyone with access to AWS will be able to reproduce your Beanstalk environment. You should also use a sample application accessible to anyone for this case.

Comment: I terminated the EC2 instance, redeployed and at least for the moment I have an updated site. For testing I am running a micro instance, I don't know if that would cause any of the issues. I will keep an eye on future deployments because I don't want to have to terminate the instance after each deployment.